# What programming problems are best solved by using pointers?

Tags: learning, c++, personal-projects, pointers

Well, I basically understand how to use pointers, but not how best to use them in order to do better programming.

What are good projects or problems to resolve involving the use of pointers so I can understand them better?

Comment: Ask about what programming problems are best solved using pointers, not what projects/programs. You can write a program either using pointers or not - they (projects) are simply too big a construct for a meaningful answer.

Comment: In some (usually dynamic) languages you don't have explicit pointers: that is, absolutely everything behaves as a (safe) pointer. Do you "use" pointers in this scenario?

Comment: Programming problems are created using pointers, not solved. :)

Comment: Are object references covered by this question?

Comment: Numbercrunching?

Comment: Actually, I wonder which problems can be solved without pointer. Very few for sure.

Comment: @deadalnix, it depends if you mean explicit pointers or implicit pointers. If you mean implicit pointers (ie, there are pointers used somewhere), then it would be impossible to write any program that uses the stack or the heap. If you mean explicit pointers then you are unrestrained, you can do any size of allocation by creating new stack frames (basically using a function call) and deallocation using tail calls, assuming they are optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: Moving data to and from some packed binary format is often easier to implement with pointers. Not by a wide margin, though, and not if you're not well-versed in their use.

Comment: ugh, some of these answers are awful.

Comment: *All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection

Comment: @dan_waterworth with higher level languages, you call code from standard lib or VM that manipulate pointer for you. I some way or another, you are using pointer and if you are not, somebody else has done the dirty job for you.

Comment: @deadalnix, I assumed we were talking about C/C++. Practically every dynamic language uses references for everything and in my book, they are just pointers too.

Comment: What programming problems are best *caused* by pointers?

Comment: When looking at some of the answers, it becomes obvious that there's some ambiguity and/or disagreement in terms between whether a reference counts as a pointer or not.  Which is a big deal.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Manipulating large amounts of data in memory is where pointers really shine.

Passing a large object by reference is equivalent to just passing along a plain old number. You can manipulate the needed parts directly as opposed to copying an object, altering it, then passing back the copy to be put in place of the original.

Comment: This is a great answer and I would add that you don't need large objects to be manipulating large amounts of data; occasionally manipulating large objects will do it, but an even more common problem is manipulating a bunch of small objects really really frequently. Which, if you think about it, is just about all computer programs.

Answer (score 44):

The pointer concept allows you to refer to data by address without duplicating the storage of data. This approach allows for writing efficient algorithms such as:

1. **Sorting**
   When moving data in a sort algorithm you may move the pointer instead of the data itself—think of sorting millions of rows on a string of 100 chars; you save a lot of unnecessary data movements.
2. **Linked lists**
   You can store the next and/or previous item location and not the entire data associated with the record.
3. **Passing parameters**
   In this case, you pass the address of the data instead of the data itself. Again, think of a name compression algorithm that runs on millions of rows.

The concept can be extended to data structures such as relational databases where a pointer is akin to a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). Some language don't encourage the use of pointers such as C# and COBOL.

Examples can be found in many places such as:

- [Why use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers)
- [Why C has Pointers](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyCPointers.html)
- [The C Book's chapter on pointers](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/pointers.html)
- [IBM's example program using pointers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03example_prog_pointers.htm)

The following post may be relevant in some way:

- [Do the young minds need to learn the pointer concepts?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105902/do-the-young-minds-need-to-learn-the-pointer-concepts/105908#105908)

Comment: I wouldn't say C# doesn't encourage the use of pointers; instead, it doesn't encourage the use of *unmanaged* pointers - there's plenty of stuff in C# that gets passed around by reference instead of value.

Comment: Nice one ,good explanation

Comment: Had to downvote for the C# comment. C# "references" are equivilent to pointers, it's just that C# abstracts you away from knowing that really you're just dealing with a pointer to an object in the managed heap.

Comment: @MattDavey: C# references are not pointers. You cannot add from them, use them to index an array, use multiple indirection, etc. You can't have references to references, for instance.

Comment: @Billy ONeal the usage scenarios that you mention do not define what a pointer **is**. In its base definition, a "pointer" is a language type which refers directly to another value in memory using its address. By that definition, C# references are pointers, although as I said C# works very hard to abstract that. The fact that C# references implicitly resolve back to the object on the heap means most .NET developers aren't even aware of the indirection.

Comment: @Matt: You can't be a .NET developer and not be aware of that interaction; that's required for simple things like `new` to make sense. And C# references are not pointers even by your restricted definition; because if it was something like an address, you would be able to perform arithmetic on such a type. You can't do that with C# references, therefore C# references are not pointers.

Comment: @Billy ONeal the notion that "it's only a pointer if you can do arithmetic on it" is frankly ludicrous, but I don't have the patience to argue with you.

Answer (score 29):

I'm surprised no other answer has mentioned this: pointers allow you to create non-contiguous and non-linear data structures, wherein an element may be related to multiple others in complex ways.

Linked lists (singly, doubly, and circularly linked), trees (red-black, AVL, trie, binary, space partitioning…), and graphs are all examples of structures that can be constructed most naturally in terms of references rather than just values.

Comment: You're forgetting the XOR linked list [=

Comment: @dan_waterworth: No. I know that black magic all too well.

Answer (score 8):

One simple way is in Polymorphism. Polymorphism only works with pointers.

Also, you use pointers any time you need dynamic memory allocation. In C, this usually happens when you need to store data into an array but you do not know the size at compile time. You would then call malloc to allocate the memory and a pointer to access it. Also, whether you know it or not, when you use an array you are using pointers.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   std::cout << array[i];
```

is the equivalent of

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   std::cout << *(array + i);
```

This knowledge allows you to do really cool things like copy an entire array in one line:

```
while( (*array1++ = *array2++) != '\0')
```

In c++, you use new to allocate memory for an object and store it into a pointer. You do this anytime you need to create an object during run-time instead of during compile time (i.e. a method creates a new object and stores it into a list).

To understand pointers better:

1. Find some projects that play around with traditional c-strings and arrays.
2. Find some projects that use inheritance.
3. Here is the project that I cut my teeth on:

Read in two n x n matrices from a file and perform the basic vector space operations on them and print their result to the screen.

To do this, you have to use dynamic arrays and refer to your arrays by pointers since you will have two arrays of arrays (multi-dimensional dynamic arrays). After you finish that project, you will have a pretty good idea how to use pointers.

Comment: "Polymorphism only works with pointers." Not accurate: polymorphism also works with references. Which are, ultimately, pointers, but I think the distinction is important, especially to the newbies.

Comment: your example for copying an array in one line is really for copying a zero-terminated string in one line, not any general array.

Answer (score 8):

To truly understand why pointers are important you need to understand the difference between heap allocation and stack allocation.

The following is an example of a stack allocation:

```
struct Foo {
  int bar, baz
};

void foo(void) {
  struct Foo f;
}
```

Objects allocated on the stack only exist for the duration of the current function execution. When the call to `foo` goes out of scope so does the variable `f`.

One case where this becomes an issue is when you need to return something other than an integral type from a function (for example the Foo structure from the example above).

For example, the following function would result in so-called "undefined behavior."

```
struct Foo {
  int bar, baz
};

struct Foo *foo(void) {
  struct Foo f;
  return &f;
}
```

If you want to return something like `struct Foo *` from a function what you really need is a heap allocation:

```
struct Foo {
  int bar, baz
};

struct Foo *foo(void) {
  return malloc(sizeof(struct Foo));
}
```

The function `malloc` allocates an object on the heap and returns a pointer to that object. Note that the term "object" is used loosely here, meaning "something" rather than object in the sense of object-oriented programming.

The lifetime of heap-allocated objects is controlled by the programmer. The memory for this object will be reserved until the programmer frees it, i.e. by calling `free()` or until the program exits.

**Edit**: I failed to notice this question is tagged as a C++ question. The C++ operators `new` and `new[]` perform the same function as `malloc`. The operators `delete` and `delete[]` are analogous to `free`. While `new` and `delete` should be used exclusively to allocate and free C++ objects, the use of `malloc` and `free` is perfectly legal in C++ code.

Comment: (+1) also known as "static allocated variables" and "dynamic allocated variables" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Write any non-trivial project in C and you WILL have to figure how/when to use pointers. In C++ you will mostly use RAII-enabled objects which manage pointers internally, but in C raw pointers have a much more prevalent role. As for what kind of project you should do, it can be anything non-trivial:

- A tiny and simple web server
- Unix command line tools (less, cat, sort etc.)
- Some actual project you want to do for its own sake and not just for learning

I recommend the last one.

Comment: So I just go for a project I want to do (Like a 2D game) and it's supposed that I will need and learn pointers ?

Comment: In my experience, doing real projects that are slightly out of your reach skill-wise is the best way to learn. Concepts can be learned by reading and writing small "toy" programs. However, to really learn how you can use those concepts to write better programs, you simply have to write non-toy programs.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all programming problems that can be solved with pointers can be solved with other safer types of [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29) (not referring to [C++ references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29), but the general CS concept of having a variable refer to the value of data stored elsewhere).

[Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) by being a specific low-level implementation of references, where you can directly manipulate memory addresses are very powerful, but can be slightly dangerous to use (e.g., point to memory locations outside the program).

The benefit of using pointers directly is that they'll be slightly faster by not having to do any safety checks.  Languages like Java that don't directly implement C-style pointers will suffer a slight performance hit, but will reduce many types of difficult to debug situations.

As for why you need indirection, the list is fairly long, but essentially the two key idea are:

1. Copying values of big objects is slow and will make the object be stored in RAM twice (potentially very costly), but copying by reference is near instantaneous using only a few bytes of RAM (for the address).  E.g., say you have ~1000 big objects (each being about say 1MB of RAM) in memory, and your user needs to be able to select the current object (which will be acted upon by the user).  Having a variable `selected_object` that is a reference to one of the objects is much more efficient than copying the value of the current object into a new variable.
2. Having complicated data structures that refer to other objects like linked lists or trees, where each item in the data structure refers to other items in the data structure.  The benefit of referring to other items in the data structure means that you don't have to move every item in the list around in memory just because you inserted a new item to the middle of the list (can have constant time inserts).

Answer (score 2):

Pixel level image manipulation is almost always easier and faster using pointers. Sometimes it is only possible using pointers.

Comment: I don't think the statement "sometimes it is only possible using pointers" is true. There are languages that don't expose pointers to the developer, yet they can be used to solve problems in the same space.

Comment: Perhaps...I don't have knowledge of all available languages, but I certainly wouldn't want to write a routine to apply a convolution filter to an image using a language that doesn't have pointers.

Comment: @Thomas, while you are correct, the question is about c++ which does expose pointers to the developer.

Comment: @Jonathan Even so, if you can solve a problem in a language that doesn't expose pointers, then it's also possible to solve that problem in a language that does expose pointers without using pointers. That makes the first sentence true, but the second sentence false - there are (to the best of my knowledge) no problems that can't be solved without the use of pointers.

Comment: @Thomas, this would be a great discussion for you to start as a question, as I'd love to explore this more. Anyhow, I have two thoughts. 1st, most languages that don't expose pointers to programmers are still using them in the background, so they have not taken away the pointers, they have just hidden their complexity (I guess even C does this with arrays somewhat). 2nd, I have yet to see a linked list that didn't use pointers. The  only reason the developer can solve the problem in the same space without pointers is because they are hidden, not because they aren't there.

Comment: In image processing, a pixel pointer is always "bound" to the same image - once created, you can modify the pointer to point to other pixels on the same image, but never a different image. It was not really different from an array index which is required to be within-bounds.

Comment: On the contrary, image processing often involves "coordinate arithmetic" - say, taking the sine and cosine of an angle and multiplying it with the x- and y-coordinates. In other cases wrap-around or out-of-border pixel replication is needed. In this sense, pointer arithmetic is rather inadequate.

Comment: `there are (to the best of my knowledge) no problems that can't be solved without the use of pointers` -- Syntax error, triple negatives.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are used in so many programming languages below the surface without bugging the user about it. C/C++ just gives you access to them.

When to use them: As often as possible, because copying data is inefficient.
When to not use them:  When you want two copies that can be changed individually.  (What basically will end up copying the content of object_1 to another place in memory and returning a pointer - this time pointing to object_2)

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are an essential part to any data structure implementation in C and data structures are an essential part of any non-trivial program.

If you'd like to learn why it is that pointers are so vital, then I'd suggest learning what a linked list is and trying to write one without using pointers. I haven't set you an impossible challenge, (HINT: pointers are used to reference locations in memory, how do you reference things in arrays?).

Comment: +1 for mentioning data structures, the use in algorithms is a natural consequence.

Answer (score 0):

As a real life example, building a limit order book.

the ITCH 4.1 feed, for example, has a concept of "replace" orders, where prices (and therefore, priority) can change.  You want to be able to take out orders and move them elsewhere.  Implementing a double-ended queue with pointers makes the operation very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Perusing the various StackExchange sites, I realize that it's rather in vogue to ask a question like this.  At risk of criticism and downvotes, I'll be honest.  This is not meant to troll or to flame, I am only meaning to help, by giving an honest assessment of the question.

And that assessment is as follows: This is a very strange question to ask of a C programmer.  Pretty much all it says is "I don't know C."  If I analyze a bit further and more cynically, there is an undertone of a follow-up to this "question":  "Is there some shortcut I can take to quickly and suddenly acquire the knowledge of an experienced C programmer, without devoting any time for independent study?"  Any "answer" that someone can give is no substitute for going and doing the legwork of understanding the underlying concept and its use.

I feel like it's more constructive to go learn C well, first hand, than to go on the web and ask people this.  When you know C well you won't bother asking questions like this, it will be like asking "what problems are best solved by using a toothbrush?"

Answer (score 0):

Even though pointers really shine while working with large memory objects, there is still a way to do the same without them.

The pointer are absolutely essential for so-called **dynamic programming**, it is when you don't know how much memory you'll need before your program executes. In dynamic programming you can request memory chunks during runtime and place your own data into those -- so you need pointer or references (the difference is not important here) to be able to work with those data chunks.

As long as you can claim certain memory during runtime and place your data into newly acquired memory you can then do the following:

1. You can have self-extending data structures. Those are structures that can extend themselves by claiming additional memory as long as their capacity runs out. The key property of every self-extending structure is that it consists of small memory blocks (termed nodes, list items etc. depending upon the structure) and every block contains references to other block(s). This "linked" structures build the majority of modern data types: graphs, trees, lists etc.
2. You can program using OOP (Object-Oriented Programming) paradigm. The whole OOP is based upon using not direct variables, but references to class instances (termed objects) and manipulating them. No single instance can exist without pointers (even though it is possible to use static-only classes even without pointers, that is rather an exception).

Answer (score 0):

Funny, i just answered a question about C++ and talked about pointers.

Short version is you NEVER need pointers unless 1) the library you are using forces you 2) You need a nullable reference.

If you need an array, list, string etc just have it on the stack and use a stl object. Returning or passing stl objects are fast(unchecked fact) because they have internal code that copies a pointer instead of an object and will only copy the data if you write to it. This is regular C++ not even the new C++11 which will make it easier on library writers.

#### Your question might be answered at this part

If you do use a pointer make sure its in one of these two conditions. 1) You are passing input that may be nullable. An example is an optional filename. 2) If you want to give ownership away. As in if you pass or return the pointer you do not have ANY copies of it remaining nor use the pointer you give away

```
ptr=blah; func(ptr); //never use ptr again for here on out.
```

But i havent used pointers or smart pointers for a very long time and i have profiled my application. It runs very fast.

ADDITIONAL NOTE: I notice that i do write my own structs and i do pass them around. So how do i do this without using pointers? Its not an STL container so passing by ref is slow. I always load my data list/deques/maps and such. I dont remember returning any objects unless it was some sort of list/map. Not even a string. I looked at code for single objects and i notice i do something like this `{ MyStruct v; func(v, someinput); ... } void func(MyStruct&v, const D&someinput) { fillV; }` so i pretty much return objects (multiple) or preallocate/pass in a reference to fill (single).

Now if you were writing you're own deque, map, etc you'll need to use pointers. But you don't need to. Let STL and possibly boost worry about that. You just need to write data and the solutions. Not containers to hold them ;)

I hope you now never use pointers :D. Good luck dealing with libs that force you to

Answer (score 0):

As your question is tagged C++, I will answer your question for that language.

In C++ there is a distinction between pointers and references, therefore there are two scenarios where pointers (or smart pointers) are necessary to facilitate certain behaviours. They can be used in other circumstances, however you ask how "best to use them", and in all other circumstances there are better alternatives.

### 1. Polymorphism

A base class pointer allows you to call a virtual method that is dependent on the type of object that pointer points to.

### 2. Creating persistent objects

Pointers are necessary when creating an object dynamically (on the heap instead of the stack). This is necessary when you want that objects lifetime to be longer than the scope in which it is created.

In terms of "good projects or problems to resolve", as others have said here already, any non-trivial project will make use of pointers.

Comment: Maybe someone would prefer to slice object than use pointer. Happy debugging :D

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are very useful for working with memory-mapped devices.  You can define a structure that reflects (say) a control register, then assign it to the address of the actual control register in memory and manipulate it directly.  You can also point directly to a transfer buffer on a card or chip if the MMU has mapped it into the system memory space.

Answer (score 0):

I see pointers as my index finger, we use to do a couple of things:

1. when someone asks you for something you can't carry, like where is street so and so, I would "point" at this street, and that's what we do in case of arguments by reference
2. when counting or traversing through something, we would use the same finger, and that's what we do in arrays

please forgive this poor answer